# Rigify: How to regenerate a rig while preserving custom properties of control bones?

Tags: rigify, custom-properties

I am adding Custom properties to certain controls Rigify creates. In this case to control the Iris shader of the eye to make it grow/shrink. I don't want to create a whole other control for this if I can nest it into the Main Eye control.
[image]
However every time I regenerate the rig for cleanup/tuning purposes, these custom properties go away and I have to recreate them.

I tried deselecting "Overwrite Widget Meshes" in the advanced subsection of the Rigify section of the Metarig but it still gets rid of the custom properties when regenerating.
[image]
Does Rigify have a way to preserve those custom properties when regenerating a rig or am I going to have to use the Run Script field below and automate my custom property generation ?

Comment: WORKAROUND: This doesn't answer the question but may provide a decent workaround for some cases:
If you add the custom properties to a bone in the metarig, they will appear on a corresponding control bone once the rig is generated (not always sure which one). You'll need to play around until your custom prop lands somewhere close enough to where you need it. In my case, if it's on the metarig's eye bone, it goes to the eye_Master on the control rig.
If you are hooking up drivers, that connection should remain once you set it up as long as you don't change the name of your custom property.